# Is there a stack which deals with data mapping or processing?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

Is there a stack out there that deals with data mapping or data processing?

The question concerns extracting address data from unorgainised spreadsheets and mapping it to the physical world. The main challenge is it involves information about soldiers killed in the first world war - the data is a mess and mapping it is problematic because some of the streets no longer exist.

Comment: Do [gis.se] or [scicomp.se] work?

Comment: @BenBrocka could you post that as an answer ben?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/faq) and [Geographic Information Systems](https://gis.stackexchange.com/faq) seem like possible fits to me (as a layman to both of those fields). From there I guess it depends whether you're talking about it from the scientific computing aspect or the geographic information side.